# Не работает тест на функцию

Tags: python, django

```
def save(request):
    data = {'mark':request.POST.get('mark'), 'task':request.POST.get('task')}
    Task.objects.filter(id=request.POST.get('s')).update(mark=data['mark'], task=data['task'])
    return redirect(list)
```

Тест на эту функцию, но он валиться, потому что не происходить обновление данных, подскажите, где накосячил и как правильно нужно сделать

```
def test_ok_update_task(self):
    s=1
    Task.objects.create(mark=True, task='task')
    data = {'mark': False, 'task': '1'}
    self.client.post('/save', data)
    task_1 = Task.objects.filter(id=s).get()
    self.assertNotEquals(task_1.mark, True)
    self.assertNotEquals(task_1.task, 'task')
    self.assertEquals(task_1.mark, data['mark'])
    self.assertEquals(task_1.task, data['task'])
```

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки.

Comment: @approximatenumber ошибка в том,что не обновляются данные,поэтому на этапе сравнения просто валится тест